# Manually sorting vector<int> in C++

Tags: c++, shell, sorting, stdvector

I am currently looking into how Vectors work in C++. I have read and understand their functionality pretty well.

I'm looking at different ways of sorting a vector object with 10,000 ints, I've used the std::sort method, and a shell sort.

I noticed that a shell sort for a vector is slower than sorting a simple C style array. I learnt this was because "Fast element insertion or removal in the middle of the container is not supported" (http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/vector/start). So obviously a shell sort with lots of random accesses is going to be quite slow.

I was wondering in anyones experience what a better *manual* sorting method would be for a vector with 10,000 ints? This is for a learning exercise you see! :)

Comment: Important tip: it makes sense to measure performance of STL containers only in release builds (i.e. with optimizations enabled), since in debug builds they are often slowed down by the added abstraction (more method calls, iterators, ...) and added security checks (e.g. checked iterators in VC++). In release builds, instead, there are no checks more than those required by the standard, and the optimizer is able to remove almost all the abstraction overhead.

Comment: The reason your vector is slower than a C-array is that you're doing different things with both. Be sure to not use `insert` on the vector, and be sure to use `operator[]` instead of `at()`. "So [for a `std::vector`] obviously [...] lots of random accesses is going to be quite slow" is very, very incorrect.

Comment: @rubenvb: I would certainly recommend using `at()` over `operator[]` and pray the processor branch prediction will make it smooth, yet safe.

Comment: @Matthieu: I certainly agree, but when performance matters, there is a difference, especially when comparing C-arrays with vectors.

Comment: @rubenvb: I just find unfortunate that `at` isn't the expert unchecked mode :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) or [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithms (very similar but depends on what you need). In any case, these are just relatively simple and popular algorithms - more importantly, in practice they are fast (although they do have bad worst cases).

Regards,
Dennis M.

Answer (score 9):

For all intents and purposes, vectors are arrays with added niceties. Random access is as fast as the C-style array. Removing/inserting elements in the middle of a vector is slow - but the same applies to C-style arrays, too. Shell sort should be as fast on vectors as it is on arrays. To me, it sounds like you're doing something unorthodox.

Quicksort or introsort (`std::sort` is one) should be the fastest comparison-based sorts available to you. Mergesort is slightly slower than quicksort, but it does not have quicksort's susceptibility to pathological cases. On average, all of those take O(n lg n) time (with quadratic worst-case for quicksort).

**EDITED UPDATE**

Code: [C-array](http://codepad.org/xBcLiBCE) and [Vector](http://codepad.org/ThWvyWnF) based shellsorts. With optimisations or without, sorting 1 million elements takes twice as long for vectors, for a reason unbeknown to me. Looks like STL is doing a **lot** of error-checking when you access a vector.

Comment: +1, with in-place sorting you don't need insertion or deletion.

Comment: doesn't it always do a bounds check when accessing an element in a debug build? Is this performance degradation the same in a release build?

Comment: I am pretty sure that `g++` does not do a debug-build. Also, a google search turned up that only `vector.at()` does bounds checking, but `vector[]` does not. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, first time on stackoverflow.com! I will look into quicksorts.

Comment: One difference between your C-array and Vector tests is that the array is statically initialized, while the vector is zeroed out at runtime, in resize(). That's an extra million writes for the vector.

Comment: @evgeny: I think you are correct with the bound-checking `at()` vs simple access `operator[]`. And cplusplus.com agrees with me (see http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/at/ ).

Comment: @evgeny, @rubenvb: it is correct, `at()` performs bound checking (and throw `std::out_of_range` if the index is not suitable) while `operator[]` is raw, and undefined behavior ensues if you mess up. In thight loops a difference might be noted, but I would recommend `at()` in general, and only leave it to specialized algorithms to use unchecked access.

Comment: @evgeny, @Bo: I would have suggested using `reserve` (no initialization) + `push_back` instead of `resize`, but I am not sure that the extra incrementation of `size` won't put off the gain of not initializing the elements. @evgeny: you might want to use `std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), rand)` rather than an explicit loop :)

Answer (score 2):

An algorithm such as quicksort is ideal for sorting data in-place, as one would with a vector.  That is, no insertions or deletions, just moving data around in the fixed-size buffer.